# Details about ApplicationUnderTest.Launch() method's fileName and alternateFileName arguments

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out some details about the arguments of the `ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(String, String)` method. From the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405789.aspx), they are described like this:

```
fileName
    Type: System.String
    The file name of the application to start.

alternateFileName
    Type: System.String
    The alternate file name that has environment variables.
```

My questions are:

- What is the purpose of `alternateFileName`? Is it only used when `fileName` is not found or not valid? Does the `Launch()` method always try the `fileName` first?
- Does `fileName` support environment variables in it? Does `alternateFileName` **always** require at least one environment variable in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my own experience (and a little help from a decompiler), here's what I've discovered.

> What is the purpose of `alternateFileName`?

`alternateFileName` allows you to use a path with environment variables that are expanded at run time. There is also some special handling to convert environment variables only found on a 64-bit environment to those found on a 32-bit environment, if necessary (for example, converting `%programfiles(x86)%` to `%programfiles%`).

> Is it only used when `fileName` is not found or not valid? Does the `Launch()` method always try the `fileName` first?

If you use one of the `Launch()` [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.applicationundertest.launch.aspx) that include the `alternateFileName` parameter, it is always checked first. If there is a matching file at the expanded path, then that path is used and `fileName` is never checked. If there is no matching file at the expanded `alternateFileName` path, only then will it use `fileName`.

Note: I just discovered a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1376950/executing-coded-ui-test-results-in-failedtolaunchapplicationexception-when-relying-on-alternatefilename-on-32-bit-system) present in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 where `alternateFileName` is in fact incorrectly handled on a 32-bit system. In that case, `alternateFileName` was always getting prepended with the value `C:\Windows\System32` so it would end up with a value like `C:\Windows\System32C:\Program Files\foo\bar.exe`. Since this is an invalid value, the system was only relying on `fileName`.

> Does `fileName` support environment variables in it?

No, any environment variables in `fileName` are not expanded.

> Does `alternateFileName` always require at least one environment variable in it?

No, environment variables are not required -- although I can't think of how it would be useful to supply a value for `alternateFileName` without them.

Comment: Wow, great answer, thanks a lot! If only the MSDN documentation is just half as detailed as this...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
private static ApplicationUnderTest _application;

public static ApplicationUnderTest LaunchApplicationUnderTest(string applicationPath,
         bool closeOnPlaybackCleanup)
      {
         Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyApp");

         if (processes.Length > 0)
         {
            _application = ApplicationUnderTest.FromProcess(processes[0]);
         }
         else
         {
            _application = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(applicationPath);
            _application.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = closeOnPlaybackCleanup;
         }

         return _application;
      }
```